# How to change 'Input Buffer Size' setting in Minicom

Tags: serial-port, settings, matlab, minicom

I'm using minicom to interface with a bluetooth device.  I have been able to successfully do this in matlab, however I have to first change the 'InputBufferSize' parameter in matlab from 512 to 24 before I can read or write correctly to the device.  I want to know what the equivalent setting is in minicom or if there is another program which allows me to change this parameter so I can successfully connect through the terminal.